# nodejs conflicts with node (re installing nodejs)

Tags: javascript, linux, node.js, ubuntu, npm

I am trying to reinstall node. I was screwing around a little bit trying to download a newer version.

So to uninstall I cleared out the node and node_module parts inside `usr/local/bin/ and usr/local/src`

Following these instructions

https://github.com/joysent/node/wiki/Installing-Node.js-via-package-manager#ubuntu-mint

When I run

```
xx.x@x:~/src/node-v0.10.18$ checkinstall
```

I get

```
dpkg: regarding .../node_0.10.18-1_i386.deb containing node:
 nodejs conflicts with node
  node (version 0.10.18-1) is to be installed.
  node provides node and is to be installed.
dpkg: error processing /home/hassan/src/node-v0.10.18/node_0.10.18-1_i386.deb (--install):
 conflicting packages - not installing node
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /home/hassan/src/node-v0.10.18/node_0.10.18-1_i386.deb
(END)
```

I am not sure what else I should be doing. I tried a few other things.

:(

More details

This is what shows up on the command line

```
Copying files to the temporary directory...OK

Stripping ELF binaries and libraries...OK

Compressing man pages...OK

Building file list...OK

Building Debian package...OK

Installing Debian package... FAILED!

*** Failed to install the package

Do you want to see the log file?  [y]: y


*** SIGINT received ***

Restoring overwritten files from backup...OK

Cleaning up...OK

Bye.
```

OH I solved it! I deleted all of the node related files through synaptic !! :D!

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to use my pre-built packages which are available here:

https://launchpad.net/~chris-lea/+archive/node.js

They install a `/usr/bin/nodejs` binary and then create a symlink from that to `/usr/bin/node`.

If you are going to use these, be **sure** to remove any vestiges of any previous installs so that the system is using the correct binaries.